# Reference Elements in PowerShell Multidimensional Array

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array

I have CSV file

[image]

My PowerShell Script attempts to store SourceIP, DestinationIP, and Traffic in multidimensional array

```
$source = @((Import-Csv D:\Script\my.csv).SourceIP)
$dest = @((Import-Csv D:\Script\my.csv).DestinationIP)
$t = @((Import-Csv D:\Script\my.csv).Traffic)

$multi = @($source),@($dest),@($t)
```

When I try to read from first element of $multi, I expect to get a list of SourceIP

```
foreach ($q in $multi){
    write-host $q[0]
    write-host `n
}
```

But instead, I get SourceIP, DestinationIP, Traffic, i.e.

```
10.153.128.110


10.251.68.80


3.66 GB
```

And if I try

```
foreach ($q in $multi){
    write-host $q[0][0][0]
    write-host `n

}
```

I get

```
1


1


3
```

How to troubleshoot?

UPDATE

Ultimate goal is to

1. Count total traffic
2. Count traffic if SourceIP or Destination IP fits into certain pattern, i.e. 10.251.22.x
3. Get percentage

UPDATE II

I am able to get code to import CSV and tally total bandwidth only, but I also need bandwidth from SourceIP and DestinationIP with certain pattern.

```
$t = @((Import-Csv D:\Script\my.csv).Traffic)

foreach ($k in $t){
    write-host $k

}


foreach ($i in $t){
    $j += ,@($i.split(" "))
}



foreach ($m in $j){
    switch ($m[1]){
        GB {
            $m[0] = [int]($m[0]) * 1000
            $m[1] = 'MB'
        }
        MB {}
        KB {
            $m[0] = [int]($m[0]) / 1000
            $m[1] = 'MB'
        }
    }
    $total_bandwidth += $m[0]
}

write-host Total bandwidth is ("{0:N2}" -f $total_bandwidth) MB
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand: what are you trying to get ?

Comment: @CB How to reference a list of SourceIP from the $multi array

Comment: you mean this: `multi[0]` ?

Comment: What is the ultimate goal? The data is already structured. Why exactly do you feel that you need to put it into another structure?

Comment: @Sonihal For your goal the imported CSV is enough...

Comment: @CB .... will research this, see updated post

Comment: @Sonihal cast your IP `[string]` to `[ipaddress]` and compare it `$ip.sortableaddress` from the limits you want and go on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not split array of object to multiple parallel arrays of properties. It is much easy to operate when objects are whole.

```powershell
$Scale=@{
     B=1e00
    KB=1e03
    MB=1e06
    GB=1e09
    TB=1e12
}
$TrafficBytes={
    $a=-split$_.Traffic
    [double]$a[0]*$Scale[$a[1]]
}

Import-Csv D:\Script\my.csv|
ForEach-Object $TrafficBytes|
Measure-Object -Sum #total traffic

Import-Csv D:\Script\my.csv|
Where-Object {$_.DestinationIP-like'10.*'}| #condition
ForEach-Object $TrafficBytes|
Measure-Object -Sum #traffic by condition
```

Answer (score 1):

PetSerAl has a good idea for the conversion, but here is a way to do this that requires iterating the CSV only once and will give your percentages.

```
$filter = "10.251.22.*"

$Scale=@{
     B=1e00
    KB=1e03
    MB=1e06
    GB=1e09
    TB=1e12
}


$myCsv = Import-Csv D:\Script\my.csv | Select-Object *, @{ Name = "TrafficBytes"; Expression = { $a = -split $_.Traffic; [double] $a[0] * $Scale[$a[1]] } }
$trafficFiltered = $myCsv | Group-Object { $_.SourceIP -like $filter -or $_.DestinationIP -like $filter } | Select-Object @{ Name = "IPFilter"; Expression = { if ($_.Name -eq $true) { $filter } else { "Other" } } }, @{ Name = "TrafficBytes"; Expression = { ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Sum "TrafficBytes").Sum } }
$trafficTotal = $myCsv | Measure-Object -Sum TrafficBytes
$trafficReport = Select-Object IPFilter, TrafficBytes, @{ Name = "Percent"; Expression = { "{0:P}" -f $_.TrafficBytes / $trafficTotal.Sum * 100.0 } }

$trafficReport
```